# Update record in cake php using key other than row id

Tags: cakephp, save, sql-update, key

I have a database table in which along with the data, `provider_id` is also unique. Now I have a set of data in which I got `provider_id` not the row id. So is it possible to edit the row using this `provider_id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use the primary key, then seems that updateAll() is your friend

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions

Answer (score 0):

Get the row you want to edit by doing something like:

```
$row = $this->ModelName->findByProviderId($data['provider_id']);
```

Now modify $row however you like:

```
$row['some_field'] = 'someValue';
```

Then you can use `Model::save()` like:

```
$this->ModelName->save($row);
```

As long as `$row` will have the primaryKey field of your model, which is generally id, `Model::save()` will perform an update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Let the model be "Contact".

```
$this->Contact->updateAll(
     array( 'Contact.any field' => 'value' ),   //fields to update ex. Contact.name
     array( 'Contact.provider_id' => $id )  //condition $id is the provider_id
);
```

Thanks